# Using enum values to represent binary operators or functions

Tags: java, enums

I'm looking for an elegant way to use values in a Java enum to represent operations or functions. My guess is, since this is Java, there just isn't going to be a nice way to do it, but here goes anyway. My enum looks something like this:

```
public enum Operator {
    LT,
    LTEQ,
    EQEQ,
    GT,
    GTEQ,
    NEQ;

    ...
}
```

where `LT` means `<` (less than), `LTEQ` means `<=` (less than or equal to), etc - you get the idea. Now I want to actually use these enum values to apply an operator. I know I could do this just using a whole bunch of if-statements, but that's the ugly, OO way, e.g.:

```
int a = ..., b = ...;
Operator foo = ...; // one of the enum values
if (foo == Operator.LT) {
    return a < b;
}
else if (foo == Operator.LTEQ) {
    return a <= b;
}
else if ... // etc
```

What I'd like to be able to do is cut out this structure and use some sort of first-class function or even polymorphism, but I'm not really sure how. Something like:

```
int a = ..., b = ...;
Operator foo = ...;
return foo.apply(a, b);
```

or even

```
int a = ..., b = ...;
Operator foo = ...;
return a foo.convertToOperator() b;
```

But as far as I've seen, I don't think it's possible to return an operator or function (at least, not without using some 3rd-party library). Any suggestions?

Comment: What are you hoping to accomplish with this? It's very unlikely that operators will ever change in Java, if that's what you're trying to abstract out.

Comment: Nope, that's not what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not only is this possible, it's used as an example in the frequently referenced [Effective Java, Second Edition by Josh Bloch](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective/).  <strike>I don't want to step on his copyright, will look for a similar example online...</strike>

Okay, the code I remembered is freely available at the website I linked earlier.  Click "Download the code samples used in this book", then look at `effective2/examples/Chapter6/Item30/Operation.java`.

Comment: the code is sooo weird. my java is too low to understand it without comments.

Comment: Is there a specific part that confuses you?  There _are_ a lot of concepts going on there, so explaining the whole thing is kind of out of scope for one SO post.

Answer (score 0):

```
int a = ..., b = ...;
Operator foo = ...;
return foo.apply(a, b);
```

it is possible to do this if foo is object and Operator is base class and concrete operators are concrete classes that implement apply.

Comment: you have abstract class "Operator" that has single method apply. there are subclasses like LessOrEqualTo that implement apply(a, b) { return a <= b; }